# Vertical text in a nested grid not aligning correctly along the horizontal (center desired)

Tags: output-formatting, options, grid-layouts, rule, alignment

I reconstructed the results of several functions that generate rows and nested grids so as to do away with the minutia. I am having difficulty getting the vertical text to `Alignment -> {Center,Center}` and I cannot figure out why. I am certain it is something very trivial to fix. I believe I may be able to play around with `Spacings -> {specs}` but that cannot be the right way. I really want to nail this down. Also please feel free to rewrite any options that you feel could be done better.

```
Clear[A2, B2, C2, D2, vec, grid, topgrid];
A2 = TraditionalForm[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {2, 2}]];
B2 = TraditionalForm[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {2, 2}]];
C2 = TraditionalForm[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {2, 2}]];
D2 = TraditionalForm[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {2, 2}]];
vec = {1, 2, 3};
grid = Grid[{{"A2 \[Rule]", A2}, {"B2 \[Rule]", B2}, {"C2 \[Rule]", 
    C2}, {"D2 \[Rule]", D2}, {"vec \[Rule]", vec}}, 
  Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Center}, 
  Spacings -> {{4, {.5}, 4}, {2, {1}, 2}}, Frame -> True]
topgrid = Grid[{
   {Rotate[Style["sideheading", Bold], 90 Degree], grid}
   }, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> True
  ]
```

Comment: Does `Spacings -> {{2, 1}, 1}` look better to you ? It looks a bit more central to me.

Comment: @flinty yeah i did a similar fix with `Spacings` "pattern rules" but I was hoping to solve what was causing this anomaly.